# Redirect to app store or google store after button click

Tags: javascript, php

I have a button on my PHP page, currently I'm using this javascript code to open the `app store` and `play store`, but this code will directly open the `play store` and `app store` page and not on the button click, I want it to open after the user click on the button and it will open based on the browser agent. Can anyone help me?

```
 <script> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
     if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1){
         window.location.href = 'https://itunes.apple.com/my/app/flipbizz/idexampleapp';
     }
    });
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
     if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
         window.location.href = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exampleapp';
     }
    });
</script>

  <p><button> JOIN ME NOW</button></p>
</div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Add an `onclick` to the button.

Comment: The use of jQuery here is very inteligent. You code 20 lines when only two were needed. Cool.

Comment: can you be more specific which part should i add it? iam a newbie here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1){ window.location.href = 'https://itunes.apple.com/my/app/flipbizz/idexampleapp'; }

    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){ window.location.href = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exampleapp'; }

    //Update #2
    if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
         window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; //Desktop Browser
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's my pleasure. =)

Comment: if i want it to be open in dekstop browser ? what should i add ?

Comment: if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
}